# Why is this useEffect doesn't render my component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

i'm trying to use this use effect in my project but it makes my component fails to render correctly:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setFavoriteContact((item) => {
      const favorites = window?.localStorage?.getItem("favorites")
        ? JSON.parse(`${localStorage.getItem("favorites")}`)
        : [];

      const favoritas = [...item, ...favorites];

      contacts.forEach((item) => {
        const firstLetter = item.last_name.charAt(0).toUpperCase();

        if (favoritas.includes(`${item.last_name} ${item.first_name}`)) {
          if (!favoriteContactGroup[firstLetter]) {
            favoriteContactGroup[firstLetter] = [];
          }
          favoriteContactGroup[firstLetter].push(item);
        } else {
          if (!normalContactGroup[firstLetter]) {
            normalContactGroup[firstLetter] = [];
          }
          normalContactGroup[firstLetter].push(item);
        }
      });

      return favoritas;
    });
  }, []);
```

after some tinkering i found out that if i modify the code like this, then now it renders correctly albeit having some awkward delay before showing the data (it doesn't instantly put the favorite contact in the right place):

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const favorites = window?.localStorage?.getItem("favorites")
      ? JSON.parse(`${localStorage.getItem("favorites")}`)
      : [];
    setFavoriteContact((item) => [...item, ...favorites]);
  }, []);

  contacts.forEach((item) => {
    const firstLetter = item.last_name.charAt(0).toUpperCase();

    if (favoriteContact.includes(`${item.last_name} ${item.first_name}`)) {
      if (!favoriteContactGroup[firstLetter]) {
        favoriteContactGroup[firstLetter] = [];
      }
      favoriteContactGroup[firstLetter].push(item);
    } else {
      if (!normalContactGroup[firstLetter]) {
        normalContactGroup[firstLetter] = [];
      }
      normalContactGroup[firstLetter].push(item);
    }
  });
```

i need some explanation as to why the first snippet fail to render my component but the second one actually works. i've been thinking that it maybe because the value didn't get properly processed but when i console log them, it output the right values (i tried logging the normalContactGroup and favoriteContactGroup). so maybe it's because for some reason react does not re-render my component afterwards? but why?

===

Edit 1:

favoriteContactGroup and normalContactGroup are an empty object for storing the grouped contact data from my backend, they look like this initially:

```
const normalContactGroup: { [key: string]: Contact[] } = {};
const favoriteContactGroup: { [key: string]: Contact[] } = {};
```

and the data from the backend has this shape:

```
  const contactArray: Contact[] = [
    {
      _id: "6561a98995095b8c3c8b38ca",
      contact_id: "6561a98995095b8c3c8b38c6",
      first_name: "Poppy",
      last_name: "Abba",
      default_number: "980891",
      phone_numbers: 2,
      createdAt: "2023-11-25T08:00:09.442Z",
      updatedAt: "2023-11-25T08:00:09.442Z",
      __v: 0,
    },
    {
      _id: "6561a97695095b8c3c8b38c4",
      contact_id: "6561a97695095b8c3c8b38c0",
      first_name: "Berkley",
      last_name: "Arkham",
      default_number: "89701234",
      phone_numbers: 2,
      createdAt: "2023-11-25T07:59:50.618Z",
      updatedAt: "2023-11-25T07:59:50.618Z",
      __v: 0,
    },
  ];
```

but after that processing, they turn to be like this:

```
{
  "A": [
    {
      "_id": "6561a98995095b8c3c8b38ca",
      "contact_id": "6561a98995095b8c3c8b38c6",
      "first_name": "Poppy",
      "last_name": "Abba",
      "default_number": "980891",
      "phone_numbers": 2,
      "createdAt": "2023-11-25T08:00:09.442Z",
      "updatedAt": "2023-11-25T08:00:09.442Z",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "6561a97695095b8c3c8b38c4",
      "contact_id": "6561a97695095b8c3c8b38c0",
      "first_name": "Berkley",
      "last_name": "Arkham",
      "default_number": "89701234",
      "phone_numbers": 2,
      "createdAt": "2023-11-25T07:59:50.618Z",
      "updatedAt": "2023-11-25T07:59:50.618Z",
      "__v": 0
    },
  ],
}
```

Comment: You have added a function declaration and definition in useEffect but even though useEffect will run at the time of rendering, but  function should have been called in order to execute the code inside explicitly.

Comment: which function are you referring to? is it the contacts.forEach? do you mean i have to call my contacts.forEach function? hasn't that already got invoked?

Comment: What are ```favoriteContactGroup``` and ```normalContactGroup```? Can you update your question to include how they are defined and where. Also I don't think it is good idea to do side effects inside setState callback

Comment: sure, i've added each requested variable in the post. if it is not recommended to do side effects like that, do you have an advice for the change?

Comment: There is still no information where they are declared. Inside or outside of the component

Comment: The first useEffect does not affect state so the component will not update.

Comment: right, they're all inside the same component. so all of those objects and const are inside a ContactCard component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rerender` means executing the body of the component again and again. Since you defined them just as regular variables

```
const normalContactGroup: { [key: string]: Contact[] } = {};
const favoriteContactGroup: { [key: string]: Contact[] } = {};
```

Their values get reset to empty objects on each render.

In your first example you update their values, but since the rerender happens after that, their values got reset.

Second example updates their values after the rerender. So on every rerender they get reset and update again and again

You should not do side effects inside setState callback. It should only return the new state

Answer (score 0):

There three cases for `useEffect`

1- if you want it to be executed in each render you should not specify the array of prop, like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  //Runs on every render
});
```

2- if you want it to be executed just at the first render, same as `componentDidMount`, use it like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  //Runs only on the first render
}, []);
```

3- if you want it to be executed depending on the change of a value or multiple values, use it like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  //Runs on the first render
  //And any time any dependency value changes
}, [value1, value2]);
```

Comment: Please also be aware that useEffect runs _after_ the component renders.